# Getting constant NSStrings with otool

Tags: ios, objective-c, otool

Im trying to restore iOS application from .ipa file and need to find all constant strings in it... Im using otool and dont know how to do it. I can get all selector names by command

```
otool -arch armv7 -v -s __TEXT __objc_methname MyAppBin
```

but can't figure out how to get constant strings. Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Comment: @userXXX "dont work" is useless